# TweenJs - rotate rectangle on click runs only once

Tags: javascript, createjs, tweenjs

I am trying to create simple animation on "click" event in JavaScript library called TweenJs (part of CreateJs suite), but it seems that animation updates the display only the first time when I click on the rectangle. After animation is over for the first time, on every next click it seems that code is running, but the display stands still (or doesn't update). You can see in the console that it logs start and the end of animation.

Can someone please help me and explain what is the problem with my code, and also, in general is this the right approach to use `stage.update()` ?

Here is my code:

https://codepen.io/milan_d/pen/rNaJEKY?editors=1111

**Thank you very much!**

Comment: OK people, I have found solution to this problem. Can someone please tell me what to do now? Should I post the solution here and in what form, as a comment, or to give an answer to my own question? 
Thanks!

Comment: Recommend posting an answer. I can post an easy solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that once you rotate it, it is already rotated to the angle you specify in subsequent clicks.

An easy solution is to just add a zero-duration `to()` call when you click it that resets it.

```
createjs.Tween.get(square)
    .to({rotation:0}) // This one has no duration, so it is immediate
    .to({rotation:360},3000)
    .call(squareRotationComplete);
```

Another option is to always rotate it based on the initial tween

```
createjs.Tween.get(square)
    .to({rotation:square.rotation + 360},3000)
    .call(squareRotationComplete);
```

Lastly, you could use the [RelativePlugin](https://createjs.com/docs/tweenjs/classes/RelativePlugin.html). First install it, and then just use "+360" in your `to()` call.

```
createjs.RelativePlugin.install(); // Run once
createjs.Tween.get(square)
    .to({rotation:"+360"},3000) // Note the value.
    .call(squareRotationComplete);
```

Cheers!

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thanks for the detailed answer and for the info on RelativePlugin. Cheers :)